# Why is BitBlt slower when using GetWindowDC(NULL)?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

**Purpose**
This code is part of a screen capture/app capture application that I am working on.

**Question**
In this example I am trying to capture Firefox which is maximized and fits the whole screen. I have omitted the code that comes after BitBlt because it is not relevant. My question is why does Bitblt take 10 times longer when I use GetWindowDC(NULL) obtaining the device context of the entire screen opposed to when I use GetWindowDC(FireFoxHWND)?

**Code**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    {
        std::cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";
    }

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart) / 1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart - CounterStart) / PCFreq;
}

void BitBltFunc(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC device_context = GetWindowDC(hwnd);
    if (!device_context)
    {
        std::cout << "Error creating device context" << std::endl;
    }

    HDC hdc_capture = CreateCompatibleDC(device_context);

    int width = GetDeviceCaps(device_context, HORZRES);
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(device_context, VERTRES);
    HBITMAP hbm_screen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(device_context, width, height);

    if (!hbm_screen)
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't create compatible bitmap" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        HBITMAP bmp_old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdc_capture, hbm_screen);
        if (!BitBlt(hdc_capture, 0, 0, width, height, device_context, 0, 0, SRCCOPY))
        {
            std::cout << "Bitblt failed" << std::endl;
        }

        SelectObject(hdc_capture, bmp_old);
        DeleteObject(hbm_screen);
    }
    DeleteObject(hdc_capture);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, device_context);
    std::cout << "Finished BitBlt" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    HWND mozilla_window = FindWindow(TEXT("MozillaWindowClass"), NULL);
    if (!mozilla_window)
    {
        std::cout << "Cannot find mozilla window" << std::endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        StartCounter();
        BitBltFunc(mozilla_window);
        std::cout << GetCounter() << "\n";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
    {
        StartCounter();
        BitBltFunc(NULL);
        std::cout << GetCounter() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Are the two not bitblt-ing the same amount of pixels?

Comment: Pretty normal with Aero enabled.  BitBlt() is then not just a straight copy from the video adapter memory anymore.  When you blit the desktop it then needs to composite all of the windows on the desktop, not just the single one.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant So that means in Windows 8 and 10 this will always be the case?

Comment: That is an easy guarantee, Aero cannot be turned off anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant So the successor to GDI, that being Direct2D, will it ever be ready for primetime ;-)  It didn't work out so great with our client code on Win7, but will profile it again on Win10 soon.

Comment: Hmya, if you have no idea what they tried to do then it all looks like it sucks more than XP.